# Vuescan cannot find Canon MF621 printer/scanner

Tags: networking, canon, scanner

I'm struggling with vuescan. Tried to make it work under Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 16.04 and 17.04. Also different versions of vuescan (8.x, 9.x). The program starts, but cannot find the scanner neither connected by LAN nor by USB.
I sent those Information to vuescan support:

I got one dual-boot desktop with Win7_64bit and ubuntu 16.04 OS. On Win I can use the Canon-drivers to install the MF621. Everything works fine.
On ubunbtu linux the printer driver do their job too. Printing works well. But Vuescan cannot discover the scanner during start-up. I tried to install on other PCs (Toshiba Laptop, Asus shuttle). Both are running ubuntu 16.04. Both show same result.
Further on I tried with older versions of VueScan - no success.
I tried a USB-connection on the Toshiba laptop to the MF621, but VueScan cannot detect neither.
There is no firewall activ on the ubuntu machines. To avoid any other influences from the network I set up one hub and connected the desktop, the Canon MF621 and the Toshiba Qosmio only.
The desktop is running on Win7_64 and wireshark network analyser active.
You can identify the devices as follows:
Desktop: 192.168.1.2 Bangkok01.local
Toshiba: 192.168.1.10 Qosmio
Canon MF621: 192.168.1.9 Canone001bd.local
As the printer driver is installed on Bangkok01, they know each other already.
Attached are two wireshark-screenshots:
Wireshark_Win-7-v1_Start_VueScan.jpg
Wireshark_Linux-v1_Start_VueScan.jpg
The Win-7 sheet shows in line 9 and 10 a query from Bangkok01, followed from a reply by scanner.
The linux sheet shows in line 12 to 14 the same, but in a different order. Followed by further queries.

The question is very simple: why does Vuescan not recognice the reply from the scanner?

[Vuescan Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HRxU.jpg)

[Vuescan Win-7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP4Fr.jpg)

Vuescan support assumed the following:
"The mDNS response just isn't getting delivered
to VueScan.
I'm guessing some software on your system is
intercepting this and preventing it from being
delivered to VueScan."

As I cannot find any helpful information neither in the Ubuntu forums nor other sources of the internet, I really need help how to approach this problem.

Comment: did you try the ubutnu scanner software `Sane`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Same result. Sane cannot detect the canon scanner, but detects an USB scanner (Canon LIDE 110).